# Открытие файла в блокноте

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема при открытии программно файла в блокноте.

```
        string tmp = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        tmp = tmp.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
        Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", tmp);
```

При двойном нажатии на строчке в listbox'e открывается блокнот и выскакивает ошибка "Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метки тома." Это очень странно, т.к. я экранирую слешы и ошибки не должно быть...

Я попробовал создать строку, а в ней записать путь к файлу (естественно экранируя слешы, строка типа "C:\[file.txt](http://file.txt)"), файл замечательно открылся в блокноте и этот факт меня совсем поставил в тупик... В чем ошибка и что я делаю не так я не понимаю...

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FindFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Step = 0;
            progressBar1.PerformStep();

            string TmpFile = "";
            int NumberFiles = 0;
            List<string> FileOfName = new List<string>();

            System.String path = PathFile.Text;

            try
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, SelectType.SelectedItem.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    StreamReader FindFile = new StreamReader(file);
                    string str = "";
                    while (!FindFile.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        str = FindFile.ReadLine();
                        if ((str.IndexOf(Substring.Text) > -1) && !TmpFile.Equals(file))
                        {
                            FileOfName.Add(file);
                            TmpFile = file;
                            NumberFiles++;
                        }
                    }    
                }

                if (NumberFiles != 0)
                {
                    int StepProgressBar = NumberFiles / 100;
                    progressBar1.Step = StepProgressBar;

                    foreach (string s in FileOfName)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(s + "\n");
                        progressBar1.PerformStep();
                    }                        
                }
                else
                {
                    progressBar1.Step = 100;
                    progressBar1.PerformStep();
                    MessageBox.Show("По указанному пути введенная вами строка не найдена");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tmp = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //tmp = tmp.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
            MessageBox.Show(tmp);
            Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: видемо в ListBox криво путь прописан.
покажи что тама.

Comment: вроде там все нормально

foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, SelectType.SelectedItem.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories))

                {

                  здесь я проверяю условие и записываю путь в List<T>

                }

ну а потом циклом из List пишу в listbox

Comment: у меня все нормально открывается (и без Replace тоже). 
посмотри чему равен tmp перед открытием.

Comment: я смотрел, без Replace там обычный путь C:\file.txt

Comment: прошу проект в студию.

Comment: http://narod.ru/disk/59334416001.a06173f22a6c752bc3d87880425b175f/FindFile.7z.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Замени 
listBox1.Items.Add(s + "\n");
// на 
listBox1.Items.Add(s);
// или
Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", tmp.Trim());
```

Comment: спасибо, вот я олень...

Answer (score 1):

Замечение
Если перед началом строки поставить @, то компилятор будет понимать строку дословно.